# Full picture of our galaxy from the outside

Tags: milky-way

How far a spaceship should travel to take a full picture of our own galaxy from the outside?

Comment: Cameras have lenses that cover different angles, including cameras that can cover 360 degrees, so technically you could take a photo of the entire galaxy without going anywhere.  There is no single answer to your question, IMO.

Comment: Imagine the galaxy as a disk with $\approx$ 40000 light years radius. How far away should you go?